# Postgres Table is foreign key to multiple tables

Tags: database, postgresql, foreign-keys

I have a situation and would appreciate some help.
I have two tables - Error and Warning:

```
Error   : Err_no, pattern(pk=Error_no)
Warning : War_no, pattern(pk=War_no)
```

Based on these tables I have to decide on the resolution and I have a separate table doing this:

```
Resolution : Code_no, resolution
```

I want to keep `Code_no` as foreign key to both `Err_no(Error table)` and `War_no(Warning table)`.
I am using `Postgres` and want to know if and how I can do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can redesign you tables,merge tables Error and Warning to one table:Message

> Message:(Msg_no,parrern,type(pk=Msg_no))

using column type to distinguish error or warning.then you can keep Code_no as foreign key to Message(Msg_no).

Comment: yeah, I guess redesign would be a better option, thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 2):

A foreign-key can reference one-and-only-one primary-key table - so you won't be able to have Code_no reference both tables.